# 24 hour clock regex for javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following javascript regex i came up with to validate that a user enters a valid 24 hour clock time:

```
/^([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)$/
```

It works how I expect, except it does not require the colon (:) between. How can I alter this regex to require the colon?

Comment: reading a basic regex tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove [the `?` character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) from behind your existing colon :

```
/^([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$/
```

The `?` character is a quantifier on the previous character or group to indicate it is optional (i.e. it can occur 0 or 1 times).

Answer (score 1):

The `?` after your colon `:` means that it

> Matches the preceding item (*in this case, the `:`*) 0 or 1 time.
>
> ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp))

So, if you remove that, it'll be required instead of optional.

```
/^([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$/
```